# How to add custom progress bar in wix

Tags: wix

I need to perform some actions before installing the product.
How to show the progress in the dialogue?
Is it possible in wix toolset?

Comment: It might help to say what it is you're doing. It's also not very clear why you believe that progress for your "actions before installing the product" can be shown on the progress bar DURING the actual installation.

Comment: I mean  I need to find devices and show them in progress bar while searching;  after that I want the user to choose among found devices some that are needed and so to continue installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer manages that progress bar, not WiX, therefore there is doubtless not abundant you'll be able to do concerning.

However it will report correct progress solely on activities that it is aware of the time for. If you run a bunch of custom actions then the install cannot skills long your code can last. equally if you decision self-registration on COM things Windows cannot skills long the code can last. It does not skills long it takes for any of your services to start out.

There square measure things like this if have long running custom actions and you wish reach be accurate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367525(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe it might facilitate to require a wordy log of the install and match the activities with progress bar reversals or no matter you are seeing.